# amazon-connect-chatjs failling when I do the import

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone please assist How do I fix this issue?

```
    Response
    {
      "errorType": "ReferenceError",
      "errorMessage": "connect is not defined",
      "trace": [
        "ReferenceError: connect is not defined",
        "    at /var/task/amazon-connect-chatjs/dist/amazon-connect-chat.js:1:329329",
        "    at /var/task/amazon-connect-chatjs/dist/amazon-connect-chat.js:1:384152",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/amazon-connect-chatjs/dist/amazon-connect-chat.js:1:384156)",
        "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)",
        "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)",
        "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)",
        "    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:17)"
      ]
    }
```

This is how I am importing

```
    // import connect from 'amazon-connect-chatjs'; 
    const connect = require('amazon-connect-chatjs'); used this instead of import ****fails here...
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const Connect = new AWS.Connect();
```

I have tried to put the require(amazon-connect-chatjs) before aws sdk as mentioned by sdk not sure what i am doing wrong